# How to make asynchronous calls parallel without stalling the queued calls

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I have 50 subjects and i send 50 parallel calls and each subject returns 1 or more students data
Ex: if i send one subjectId,  `this.subjectService.getStudentsData(subjectId)`
it returns students data:

```
[
{StudentId:1,
"FirstName":'firstName', 
"ListOfSubjects":[{Subjectid:1,SubjectName:'Maths', .....somedata:[{1:a,2:b...}, {3:y,2:x...}]}},

{
StudentId:2, 
FirstName:secondName, 
.
.
ListOfSubjects:[
{Subjectid:1,SubjectName:'Maths', .....somedata:[{c:1,d:2...}, {a:y,b:x...}]}}]
```

Now i need to bind as i get user by user data but it is taking 15 mins to complete all service calls

what i used is

```
const requests: any = subjectIds.map(id => {   
            const t: any = {...data};
            t.SubjectId = [id];
          return this.studentService.getStudentsData(t);
        });
```

Comment: If you just use map the request will be send subsequential. If you want to send them in parrallel use the forkJoin method: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Comment: i need to bind to UI as i get response for each request and add the next response to the original response and so on, so i dont think forkjoin will help here

Answer (score 0):

Like `mamichels` said you can use `forkJoin` but I remember reading that `forkJoin` can only do a maximum of 6 unless if you maybe use a `dictionary`.

I would do:

```
const requests: any = combineLatest(...subjectIds.map(id => this.studentService.getStudentData(id) /* you know what should go in the argument */)
...
requests.subscribe(responseArray => console.log(responseArray));
```

==========================Edit=========================

To get notified of each request completing, I would use `merge`

```
import { merge } from 'rxjs';

const requests: any = merge(...subjectIds.map(id => this.studentService.getStudentData(id));

....
requests.subscribe(response => { /* handle each response as it returns */ }));
```

================= Okay, try the old school way ================

```
for (let i = 0; i < subjectIds.length; i++) {
  this.studentService.getStudentsData(subjectIds[i].StudentId/* again, I am not sure what goes here as argument */).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
}
```

Comment: I need each response as we get so i can bind each response to UI and so on

Comment: If there are 10 calls few are going parallel and others are being stalled till others are completed, not sure what the problem is

Comment: I think these are limitations of HTTP 1 and HTTP 2. I am not sure though.